# Browser sends http request BEFORE executing the "unload" handler

Tags: javascript, onunload, window.onunload

I just discovered the following (by setting up a number of breakpoints to both client-side and server-side code):

**If you have a `window.onunload` handler - it will execute AFTER the browser sends http-request to the new page**.

1. You navigate away to a next page
2. The browser sends http-request to the new page
3. The browser executes the unload handler and just pauses the rendering process until it finishes executing it.
4. The new page is shown.

I just tested this with both Chrome and Firefox.

How come? What do you think are the reasons for this strange behavior?

PS. Here's how I discovered this: I had an unload handler that saved some data via ajax. Then I discovered that the new page I was navigating away to - still shows old data from the DB. This got me thinking...

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec has a section [Navigating across documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigating-across-documents) that describes the procedure when you navigate to a new page in the browser (e.g. by following a link). The step that says

> Unload the Document object of the current entry, with the recycle parameter set to false.

is not performed until after it has fetched the new document.

This appears to be because following the link might not always cause the current document to be unloaded. For instance, if the response contains `Content-disposition: attachment`, the target of the link will be downloaded, but the current page won't be unloaded.